# How can i lock a device id to a particular port address

Tags: 12.04, tty, lock

I want ttyUSB0 to be always used by my GSM modem how can i do that even after restart it must not change..is there any way to lock GSM Modems id to ttyUSB0.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your `/dev` directory before and after you plug in your GSM modem. It is very likely that a softlink `/dev/gsmmodem` appears, pointing to the appropriate ttyUSB device.

Comment: Nothing named /dev/gsmmodem is created when connected ttyUSB devs are created thats all